# how to exclude parent dependency while including child

Tags: maven

i have below maven modules:

Parent:(packaging pom)
-- child-1 (packaging jar)
-- child-2 (packaging jar)

i have deployed child-2 as an artifact to nexus.

when i include child-2 dependency inside other project, while resolving the child-2 dependency it looks for parent pom dependency which is not deployed inside nexus.

i tried excluding the parent dependency like below but that did not work.

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                       <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

You either need to include the parent POM into your Nexus or you can "flatten out" the parent POM by using the flatten maven plugin in the build of child2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. can you please suggest an example on how to use flatten maven plugin to resolve the issue, it will be really appreciated. Just to be sure that you understood the maven module structure correctly i am confirming the same again:

`parent(packaging pom) has two child modules child-1(packaging jar) and child-2(packaging jar)`

Comment: See here: https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/usage.html